# Electron and Cordova for Windows build

Tags: node.js, cordova, cross-platform, electron

Electron can allow to develop desktop applications (.exe) using JavaScript, HTML and CSS. It is based on Node.js and Chromium

It seem I could also do the same using Cordova but what Cordova couldn't do that Electron can (In term of desktop applications)?

I need to build an App that can do full screen, use AppCache (manifest) and store data using IndexedDB. It need to work well with Barcode Scanner and Serial Port communication (eg: https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Apache Cordova is a platform for building native mobile applications using HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

It seems like the main difference is that Cordova targets mobile platforms and apps first and foremost, while Electron is primarily focused on desktop platforms and apps. Cordova does appear to support Windows, Ubuntu, and [OS X](https://github.com/apache/cordova-osx) desktops to some extent, however they do mention the following in the OS X repository:

> Note that the current focus of this cordova platform is to provide kiosk-like applications for OSX, that usually run fullscreen and have little desktop interaction. So there is no direct support for menus, dock integration, finder integration, documents, etc. Think of it as a mobile app running on a very big screen.

It also appears that Cordova's plugin system is not directly compatible with regular NPM packages and native NodeJS addons, so you will probably have to create some sort of plugin wrapper for `node-serialport` before you could use it in a Cordova app, or perhaps use [an existing plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/plugins/?q=serial).

Comment: As of late 2019, Cordova supports Windows/OSX platform and also can generate Electron builds for Windows & OSX

Answer (score 9):

Return on experience: I have built a mobile app with Cordova which is great for Android and iOS. Unfortunately when I wanted to deploy the app on desktop, I discovered a really poor support of these targets (missing basic plugins, limited configuration).

Conclusion: Electron seems to be better for desktop apps.

Comment: Electron doesn't target mobile at all is that right?

Comment: no, but it is quite simple to manage one single JS app and to deploy it both width Cordova and Electron.